# How to Autowire a Spring-annotated service class in a @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to inject a service-annotated class into a configuration class in a Spring Boot application, but it doesn't get injected (is set to null), which I assume is due to the Spring lifeycle.

Also, this service has an overloaded constructor that uses constructor injection, and I guess this is also a problem, as autowiring acts upon a default constructor. However, the service needs to be Spring-configured, so I don't think one can create a new instance in a Bean annotated method.

How can one solve this?

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SessionService sessionService;

    @Bean
    public SessionService sessionService() {
        return sessionService;
    }
}

public interface SessionService extends BaseCacheService<Session> {
    void extendExpiration(String key);

    String getSessionId(String key);
}

@Service
public class SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService {

    private Environment environment;
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SessionServiceImpl(Environment environment, UserService userService) {
      this.environment = environment;
      this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

If I exclude the @Bean method, then I get a compilation error:
[image: Autowire compilation error if no bean found]

Comment: Why do you have a `@Bean` method for it at all if you're using `@Service`?

Comment: Remove the `@Bean` method. The `@Service` is basically an `@Component` which gets discovered using comment-scanning. Assuming you have that setup. In short you don't need the `@Bean` method at all. Your assumption is wrong, auto wiring doesn't depend on default constructors.

Comment: Can you show your SessionService interface? Because you want to autowire that interface, maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: Why do you need SessionService Interface in SecurityConfiguration? I do not really understand the use case for that. I tried different implementaion by autowire an Interface and all where ok.

Comment: @Patrick It is required by my http filter, which is initialized here. The `@Configuration` annotation seems to be causing this issue

Comment: I created a sample project and I am able to autowire the interface. I used your first approach using `@Bean` annotation. Anything else should produces the error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Your error** is the following (you are returning a null value):

```
@Bean
public SessionService sessionService() {
    return sessionService;
}
```

---

**Solution**

1. Since your `SessionServiceImpl` is annotated with `@Service`, you can just remove the `@Bean` method and let spring create it. Spring already makes it available for you.
2. Or, If your `SessionServiceImpl` wasn't annotated with `@Service`, you would need the following :

```
@Bean
public SessionService sessionService() {
   return new SessionService();
}
```

---

If this doesn't work, it may just be that your `SessionServiceImpl` is in a package not being scanned by spring (as suggested by @Miloš Milivojević)

You may add `@ComponentScan` to your Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@ComponentScan("com.package.to.sessionServiceImpl-or-higher")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Comment: Your suggestion was of course my original attempt, but then the code does not compile. It complains with "Could not autowire. No beans of 'SessionService' type found".

This is regardless of whether I annotate the service interface or class.

As I said, this is likely due to the service class having an overloaded constructor that needs to be wired up, and Spring looks for a default constructor

Comment: I added details to ensure that spring scans to find your beans

Comment: Thanks man! The `@ComponentScan` annotation sorted it out! Really would've thought that component scanning would've already happened from the main Spring Boot Application class by the time this configuration class is initialized.

It turns out that my IDE was messing around, as I removed the `@Bean` method and then started the app, and then the compilation error disappeared.
I couldn't anyway create an instance of the SessionService in a `@Bean` method, as it needs to be injected due to it's parameterized constructor requiring wired components.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Alex's answer, when you annotate a method with @Bean, it tells Spring that this method will produce that type. So, you essentially told Spring to give you the null reference you already had for all Beans of type SessionService.

If you are using Annotation-based context configuration, you can `Autowire` any `@Component` Bean (not just `@Service`) that can be constructed without runtime parameters (e.g. has a default constructor or an Autowired Constructor). If you need to do something to create the bean (e.g. runtime configuration required), you would either create a method as @Alex suggested, or you can use [getBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) and pass in the Type and Constructor arguments. The former is generally preferred.

Comment: Please see my comment on Alex's post. Do take into account the Spring lifecycle, of how and when things get wired up. I believe that that is my issue. I think that perhaps the @Configuration classes get initialized before any other annotated class.

Comment: @Razeen No, that shouldn't be the case. Unless your `@Order` annotation is making it try to create this configuration class before everything else. I don't think you should have to put `@ComponentScan` on your `Configuration` class (as you mention elsewhere, that is already included in the `SpringBootApplication`). I can `Autowire` all kinds of `Component`s in my `Configuration` classes.

Comment: @Razeen Regarding the compiler error you mention about no Bean of type <blah>, was that just from your IDE or while actually building? I know that IDEA at least has some trouble with Spring Boot because of all the automatic configuration that happens. I saw similar 'No bean' issues in the IDE when no `@Bean` method is defined, but the application works just fine. You can either disable that inspection or add `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")` to the `Autowired` fields.

Comment: I can't remember if I tried to do a rebuild, but I believe it was from the IDE. Maybe it's the Spring plugin for intellij that's not behaving 100%, or its just the IDE that got confused (something I used to get from Eclipse). 

Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to clutter the code with @SuppressWarnings annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue while writing an integration test class for a spring boot application. RestTemplate class and CounterService of metrics API are autowired in my service class. I could use @ContextConfiguration(Classes={RestTemplate.class}) for injecting RestTemplate to my service, but adding CounterService.class to above annotation does not help, maybe because CounterService is an interface not a concrete class, Hence I was getting "No bean of type CounterService found" issue.

Thanks to answer by Milos, I included @EnableAutoConfiguration to my integration test class, issue was resolved!

Answer (score 0):

If Alex's answer does not work (removing the @Bean method), you're probably not using @EnableAutoConfiguration or your Application is not in  the root-hierarchy package so it's not scanning the whole classpath. Try adding `@ComponentScan("service.class.package")` to your configuration (in addition to removing the sessionService method) and see if it helps.

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in the main class located in the root package already includes that. So it would scan for all components.